# How to compare two NAN values in C++

Tags: c++, compare, nan

I have an application in which a code area produces NAN values. I have to compare the values for equality and based on that execute the rest of the code.How to compare two NAN values in C++ for equality?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming an IEEE 754 floating point representation, you cannot compare two NaN values for equality. NaN is not equal to any value, including itself. You can however test if they are both NaN with [`std::isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) from the `<cmath>` header:

```
if (std::isnan(x) && std::isnan(y)) {
  // ...
}
```

This is only available in C++11, however. Prior to C++11, the [Boost Math Toolkit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/index.html) provides some [floating point classifiers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/utils/fpclass.html). Alternatively, you can check if a value is NaN by comparing it with itself:

```
if (x != x && y != y) {
  // ...
}
```

Since NaN is the only value that is not equal to itself. In the past, certain compilers screwed this up, but I'm not sure of the status at the moment (it appears to work correctly with GCC).

MSVC provides a [_isnan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzthab44.aspx) function.

The final alternative is to assume you know the representation is IEEE 754 and do some bit checking. Obviously this is not the most portable option.

Comment: I've added boost solution as an another answer.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Ah! I was just adding that to mine too!

Comment: Thank u all. I am sorry if the question doesn't make any sense. Just was eager to know if that is possible.'isnan' function will do something for my case.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding pre-C++11, [there's a boost for that, too](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/utils/fpclass.html).

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/fpclassify.hpp>

template <class T>
bool isnan(T t); // NaN.
```

Answer (score 1):

Any given NaN is not equal to anything, it will never be equal to any other NaN, so comparing them against each other is a futile exercise.

From GNU docs:

> NaN is unordered: it is not equal to, greater than, or less than anything, including itself.  `x == x` is false if the value of x is NaN. [source](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html)

Comment: @Aki erm, 0.0/0.0 is NaN. I don't see what is "the opposite" here.

Comment: `x != x` is the one standard compliant test that will only return `true` when `x` is `NaN`