# What is the result of comparing a number with NaN?

Tags: c++, floating-point, nan, ieee-754

Consider for example

```
bool fun (double a, double b) {
    return a < b;
}
```

What will `fun` return if any of the arguments are NaN? Is this undefined / implementation defined behavior?

What happens with the other relational operators and the equality operators?

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268864/how-to-compare-two-nan-values-in-c) address it. (I borderline think that this question is a duplicate of that, BTW.)

Comment: @AmiTavory This answer only handles the equality case.

Comment: @BaummitAugen http://stackoverflow.com/a/15268938/985296

Comment: You might be right, but I read it otherwise. From what I understand from there, you can't compare it (in any way, not only equality) with anything.

Comment: @AmiTavory I feel like this interpretation would require some proof.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Try reading again. Quoting the quote: "NaN is unordered: it is not equal to, greater than, or less than anything, including itself."

Comment: @stefan But does that mean the inequality comparison should be true, false, unspecified, or undefined?

Comment: @juanchopanza I only claim that the linked answer makes a very specific claim, namely saying that any of such comparisons returns false. I didn't say that's the standard (because I didn't check yet, hence a comment, not an answer)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The C++ standard merely says:

> **[expr.rel]/5** If both operands (after conversions) are of arithmetic or enumeration type, each of the operators shall yield `true` if the specified relationship is true and `false` if it is false.

So basically, `a < b` is true if `a` is less than `b`.

However, the implementation may claim conformance to IEC 559 aka IEEE 754 standard for floating point arithmetic, via `numeric_limits::is_iec559`. Then it is governed by that standard  in section 5.7 and table 4, which requires that all comparisons but `!=` involving `NaN` report `false`. `!=` involving `NaN` reports `true`

Comment: So would the call invoke UB or not?

Comment: It's hard to imagine an implementation that a) supports `NaN` values, but b) doesn't have them behave per IEEE 754. On any sane implementation, `a < b` is well-defined and has the value of `false` if either or both operands are `NaN`. The standard, however, is pretty vague on the topic - intentionally so, I believe, in order to cater to non-IEEE 754-conforming systems.

Comment: Can you make the IEEE part more rigorous?

Comment: No, not really. I'm not all that familiar with that standard. If you think you need more information, please feel free to look it up.

Answer (score 22):

Any comparison(except with "!=") with NaN returns false.

Here is a table I constructed:

```
     +Dbl_Nan  0_Nan  Inf_Nan  NaN_NaN  +Dbl_Inf  +Dbl_-Inf  Inf_-Inf  Inf_Inf
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
>  |  False    False  False    False     False     True      True      False
<  |  False    False  False    False     True      False     False     False
== |  False    False  False    False     False     False     False     True
!= |  True     True   True     True      True      True      True      False
```

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/2352507) for the Rationale on why NaN is always false.

Comment: Nice link, upvoted. I will leave the accept on the other answer though as I feel it is more complete from the C++ point of view.

Answer (score 1):

False.

There is really no such thing as `-NaN`, although NaN values do carry a sign bit, as well as a payload. But for arithmetic purposes, a NaN is a NaN is a NaN.

Any equality or ordered comparison with a NaN is false.

Comment: You can get the sign of a NaN with [`signbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit).

Comment: @KerrekSB: But you can't portably change the sign of a NaN with `-NaN`, only with `std::copysign`.