# Convert float to int64_t while preserving ordering

Tags: c++, floating-point, x86-64

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370587/converting-floating-point-to-unsigned-int-while-preserving-order) which deals with positive floating point values.

In my case, I'm dealing with both positive and negative `float` values, and want to store it in an `int64_t` type.

NOTE: I wish to use `memcpy` rather than relying on a union (which is UB in C++).

Comment: Are you sure that's a good idea? Have you checked `sizeof(float)` and `sizeof(int64_t)`?

Comment: I'm aware of the gotchas. Only need to support X86_64.

Comment: @jeffreyveon: Did you actually want `double` like I answered it for? I assumed that because you said `int64_t`. But if you're using `float` the int type should be `int32_t`.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: Or you'd want to put the bits at the top of an int64_t, or sign-extend, if for some reason you need to put 32-bit floats into 64-bit integers.  That might be more efficient than converting to double, especially if you want to get the `float` bit-pattern back out more efficiently (just broadcast the sign bit, logical right shift by 1, and XOR the low 31 bits.  Without needing to also do double->float FP conversion.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm actually dealing with floats so essentially do a `float -> double` conversion prior. If you can add a quick answer with a code snippet of doing this without that conversion, I will be happy to upvote and others who stumble on this question might also benefit.

Comment: Actually, instead of doing the `float -> double` conversion, I just ended up using `int32_t` and then storing that value as `int64_t`.

Comment: @jeffreyveon: yeah, you need a sign-extension at some point.  You might be able to get it for free by loading a 32-bit float bit-patterns into an int64_t temporary and flipping the low 31 bits of that based on the sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in my comment on the linked question about a 32-bit variant:

> ...basically you can either use a signed int32 and invert the low 31 bits if the sign bit is set. A similar approach works if you want unsigned but you have to add the 0x80000000 bias.

As code, adapted to 64-bit:

```
int64_t order_preserving_repr(double x)
{
    int64_t k;
    memcpy(&k, &x, sizeof k);
    if (k<0) k ^= INT64_MAX;
    return k;
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure that you don't accidentally have UB on exotic systems, I would recommend `static_assert(sizeof x == sizeof k)`

Comment: Yes, the question was about storing a `float` in an `int64_t` so the `sizeof` test would probably fail on most platforms.

Comment: @eerorika: The whole question makes no sense if you're not assuming Annex F and IEEE floating point representation, which guarantees sizes match.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Then perhaps go as far as `static_assert(std::numeric_limits<double>:: is_iec559())` to make sure that the function makes sense.