# How to prevent std::min and max to return NAN if the first element of the array is NAN?

Tags: c++, arrays, min

Is there a way to make min/max (std::min_element) ignore all NANs? I mean, it seems to ignore NANs in the middle but not if the **first element is NAN**.

Sample:

```
template <typename T> inline void GetMinMax(const T* data, const int len, T& min, T& max)
{
    min = *std::min_element(data, data + len);
    max = *std::max_element(data, data + len);
}

float min, max;
std::array<float, 4> ar1 = { -12, NAN, NAN, 13 };
GetMinMax<float>(&ar1[0], ar1.size(), min, max); //min: -12. max: 13

std::array<float, 4> ar2 = { -12, 3, 13, NAN };
GetMinMax<float>(&ar2[0], ar2.size(), min, max);//min: -12. max: 13

std::array<float, 4> ar3 = { NAN, -12, 3, 13 };
GetMinMax<float>(&ar3[0], ar3.size(), min, max);//min: -nan(ind). max: -nan(ind)  !!!!
```

Comment: Related, be aware of [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element). It finds both in a single pass.

Comment: @Pedro77 What you need is to write the algorithm minmax_element_if.:)

Comment: Which implementation are you using? gcc seems to ignore the NAN's everywhere. Edit: Oh, my bad. It just didn't change the incoming values so I don't get `-nan(ind)` but `-12 13` out for the last one, no matter what values I put in the array.

Comment: Are we allowed to change the order of elements in the array?

Comment: Hey, you are using `ar2` in the last one. That confused my results. You should change that to `ar3`. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/7s7TzfdP5)

Comment: Some interesting findings here on comparisons against NaN [What is the result of comparing a number with NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225264/what-is-the-result-of-comparing-a-number-with-nan) _"...which requires that all comparisons but != involving NaN report false..."_

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, as the built-in `<` operator doesn't satisfy the requirements of strict weak ordering in the presence of NaNs. That it appears to work when NaN is not the first element is merely an accident.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, just copy paste and run. It wasn't an accident.

Comment: @TedLyngmo mistype. Fixed now.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks for the minmax_element. But it also bugs out and returns -nan(ind) for min.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. You cannot point to the result of a program's execution as proof that the program does not exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: Tangent: https://youtu.be/2FAi2mNYjFA?t=3960 ... if you've got some time at hand check out Sean Parent's explanation on how NaN breaks find().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest path is to **remove** all the NaNs values from the range **before** applying any min-max standard algorithm.

Consider a possible implementation of `std::min_element`<sup>1</sup>:

```
template<class ForwardIt>
ForwardIt min_element(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
{
    if (first == last) return last;
 
    ForwardIt smallest = first;       // <-- If the first is a NaN...
    ++first;
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (*first < *smallest) {     // <-- This condition will always be FALSE
            smallest = first;
        }
    }
    return smallest;                  // <-- An iterator to a NaN is returned
}
```

---

More formally, the C++ Standard<sup>2</sup> specifies:

> **27.8.1**  **General**  **[alg.sorting.general]**
>
> The operations in [[alg.sorting]](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting) defined directly in namespace std have two versions: one that takes a function object of type `Compare` and one that uses an `operator<`.
>
> `Compare` is a function object type ([[function.objects]](https://eel.is/c++draft/function.objects)) that meets the requirements for a template parameter named `BinaryPredicate` ([[algorithms.requirements]](https://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements)). The return value of the function call operation applied to an object of type `Compare`, when contextually converted to `bool` ([[conv]](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv)), yields true if the first argument of the call is less than the second, and false otherwise. `Compare comp` is used throughout for algorithms assuming an ordering relation.
>
> For all algorithms that take `Compare`, there is a version that uses `operator<` instead. That is, `comp(*i, *j) != false` defaults to `*i < *j != false`. For algorithms other than those described in [[alg.binary.search]](https://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements), **`comp` shall induce a strict weak ordering on the values**.
>
> The term *strict* refers to the requirement of an irreflexive relation (`!comp(x, x)` for all `x`), and the term weak to requirements that are not as strong as those for a total ordering, but stronger than those for a partial ordering. **If we define `equiv(a, b)` as `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`, then the requirements are that `comp` and `equiv` both be transitive relations**:
>
> (4.1) `comp(a, b) && comp(b, c)` implies `comp(a, c)`
>
> (4.2) `equiv(a, b) && equiv(b, c)` implies `equiv(a, c)`

The problem, given **any** `float` value `x`, is that the following hold:

`x < NaN == false` and `NaN < x == false`, but `x != NaN`

Only considering the subset of the `float` values which are *not* NaNs we can fulfill the requirement.

---

<sup>1) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element</sup>

<sup>2) I'm quoting the draft at https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting.general , emphasis mine.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`NAN` compares with other numbers is screwy, see [What is the result of comparing a number with NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225264/what-is-the-result-of-comparing-a-number-with-nan).

So what you need to do is to provide a custom compare function so that NAN isn't the element std::min_element returns. Probably just make "NAN < x" return false and "x < NAN" return true. Similar for ">" for std::max_element. Or try overloading `<=>`.

Note: the solution might depend on your implementation of the STL, depending on which comparison operator the implementation uses.

Comment: The problem is what to return for `NaN < NaN` I can't think of a correct answer given that `NaN == NaN` is defined to be false.

Comment: true, false, does it matter. One `NaN` is as bad as another. This would only matter if the data contains only `NaN`. I would pick the answer so that the first `NaN` is returned for the STL I'm using.

Comment: With 2 NaNs (or more) in the container strict-weak-ordering would be violated leading to UB.

Comment: @RichardCritten technically true, practically not. As long as min_element < any_other_element everything will work with a sequential access. Might not work with tree based containers but they probably explode when inserting 2 `NaN` before you even get to `std::min_element`.

Comment: @RichardCritten Logically, NaN < anything is false, as is NaN > anything.  It's disconnected from the graph. In an ideal world there would be a specialization of `std::max_element` for numeric types like `double` that aren't closed under ordering, that skips NaNs.